# After returning empty function the program no longer receives input

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me with my calculator!

https://calyeefornia.github.io/Calculator/

https://github.com/Calyeefornia/Calculator/blob/master/calculator.js

Specifically line 33! Why is it that when I return an empty function, the whole calculator stops working, when i click on other buttons the inputs are not run!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `changeDisplay` function returns immediately if there is a `.` in `numbersDisplay`. So the display will never update if there is a `.` in the numbers being displayed hence the 'stops working' when using decimals.

Maybe it would be better to check if the `numbersDisplay` already includes a `.` and not add another if that is the input:

```
if(numbersDisplay.includes('.') && num == '.'){return;}
```